# Sort javascript array of objects on subobject key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects containing sub-objects like this;

```
var array=[
  {
    "EmployeeName": "John",
    "Experience": "12",
    "data":{
      "Technology":"SharePoint"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Charles",
    "Experience": "9",
      "data":{
      "Technology":"ASPNET"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Jo",
    "Experience": "3",
       "data":{
      "Technology":"PHP"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Daine",
    "Experience": "7",
      "data":{
      "Technology":"javascript"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Zain",
    "Experience": "6",
     "data":{
      "Technology":"Unity"
    }
  }
];
```

Now, I want to sort this array based on the sub-objects key "Technology". I am using the example from here: https://jsfiddle.net/KSPriyaranjan/4Lzr0qux

This does the job when it sorts from a base object, but how do I get this to work:

```
function GetSortOrder(prop){
   return function(a,b){
      if( a[prop] > b[prop]){
          return 1;
      }else if( a[prop] < b[prop] ){
          return -1;
      }
      return 0;
   }
}

array.sort( GetSortOrder("data.Technology") );

document.write("<br><br> Sorted Technology Names : <br>");

for (var item in array) {
 document.write("<br>"+array[item].Technology);
}
```

This produces this:

```
Sorted Technology Names :

undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Hope someone can help in this matter and thanks in advance :-)
undefined

Comment: `a["data.Technology"]` is not the same as `a["data"]["Technology"]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the property passed contains any `.`s, use `reduce` to navigate to the last nested value before comparison:

```
const GetSortOrder = (accessor) => {
  const getVal = accessor.includes('.')
    ? outer => accessor.split('.').reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], outer)
    : outer => outer;
  return (a, b) => getVal(a).localeCompare(getVal(b));
};
```

```js
var array=[
  {
    "EmployeeName": "John",
    "Experience": "12",
    "data":{
      "Technology":"SharePoint"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Charles",
    "Experience": "9",
      "data":{
      "Technology":"ASPNET"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Jo",
    "Experience": "3",
       "data":{
      "Technology":"PHP"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Daine",
    "Experience": "7",
      "data":{
      "Technology":"javascript"
    }
  },
  {
    "EmployeeName": "Zain",
    "Experience": "6",
     "data":{
      "Technology":"Unity"
    }
  }
];
const GetSortOrder = (accessor) => {
  const getVal = accessor.includes('.')
    ? outer => accessor.split('.').reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], outer)
    : outer => outer;
  return (a, b) => getVal(a).localeCompare(getVal(b));
};
array.sort( GetSortOrder("data.Technology") );
console.log(array);
```

The conditional isn't strictly necessary (though you may consider it to make the intent clearer), you could also do

```
const getVal = outer => accessor.split('.').reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], outer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technology is not a property of your object. It is a property of your object.data.

Try changing
  `javascript array[item].Technology`   
to
  `array[item].data.Technology`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function for getting the value by keeping your commparing approach.

```js
function GetSortOrder(prop) {
    const
        keys = prop.split('.'),
        getValue = object => keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object);
    
    return function(a, b) {
        const
            left = getValue(a),
            right = getValue(b);
        if (left > right) return 1;
        else if (left < right) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}

var array = [{ EmployeeName: "John", Experience: "12", data: { Technology: "SharePoint" } }, { EmployeeName: "Charles", Experience: "9", data: { Technology: "ASPNET" } }, { EmployeeName: "Jo", Experience: "3", data: { Technology: "PHP" } }, { EmployeeName: "Daine", Experience: "7", data: { Technology: "javascript" } }, { EmployeeName: "Zain", Experience: "6", data: { Technology: "Unity" } }];

array.sort(GetSortOrder("data.Technology"));
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```